# C# - Textbox with only letters and numbers

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, textbox

How can I limit my textbox to only accept numbers and letters?
It should not even allow spaces or anything like "!", "?", "/" and so on.
Only a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Tried this and it did not work at all

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+", txtTag.Text))
{
    txtTag.Text.Remove(txtTag.Text.Length - 1);
}
```

Not even sure if that `txtTag.Text.Remove(txtTag.Text.Length - 1);` should be there because it makes the application crash.

Comment: You have to handle keypress events. If you do, there won't be wrong characters in the text box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a regex for that:

```
        textBox1.Text = string.Concat(textBox1.Text.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
```

This will remove everything that is not a letter or digit, and can be placed in the TextChanged event. Basically, it gets the text, splits it into characters and only pick what is a letter or digit. After that, we can concatenate it back to a string.

Also, if you'd like to place the caret at the end of the textbox (because changing the text will reset its position to 0), you may also add `textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length + 1;`

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly! Now I just gotta figure out the rightclick and ctrl+v part :)

Comment: Thanx for saving my time works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
             && !char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My thought is you could alter the *KeyPressed* or *TextChanged* events for that control to check if the characters entered are numbers or letters. For example, to check the characters as they are added in the textbox you could do something like the following :

```
myTextbox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(myTextbox_KeyPress);



void myTextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar >= Keys.A && e.KeyChar <= Keys.Z)

    // you can then modify the text box text here
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code for the letter and numbers:

```
Void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender,KeyPressEventArgs e) {

// allows only letters or numbers
if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

First of all, check out [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) for some information.

I think what you should do on the client side is to add the `pattern` attribute in the corresponding HTML.

`<input type="text" name="foo" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]" title="Please input only letters and numbers">`

Comment: the question is about WinForms, not web/html